# Where are the error logs stored for the Windows Azure storage emulator?

Tags: azure

I am trying to start the Azure storage emulator, to no avail.

Init runs fine, but start does not, and I want to have a look at the logs to find out why.

Where are these log files stored?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SDK are your using - 2.3 or version before that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of running a bittorrent client before I tried to start the emulator.

Turn the bittorrent client off, turn the emulator on, and then then turn the bittorent client back on, solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Azure storage emulator log is stored in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0\UsageLogs\WAStorageEmulator.exe.log

Comment: My storage emulator is running fine but I cant see the logs where you say!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have "some" logs here: C:\Users\<YOUR_WINDOWS_USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0\UsageLogs\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.log

You might as well look at this document [here](https://juhap.iki.fi/azure/enable-debug-log-in-azure-storage-emulator/)
. It shows how to enable the logs. Basically it says:

> Head to the Storage Emulator data directory, which is located at 
>   %LOCALAPPDATA%\DevelopmentStorage.

(Actually in my case it is in %LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureStorageEmulator)

> Edit the the developmentstorage configuration file located in the directory and change the LoggingEnabled to true
>
> Restart Storage Emulator
>
> The logs will appear in the logs directory.